# Does kufr also occur when done on condition like divorce on condition?

Tags: kufr

I have found out that divorce also occurs automatically when given on condition. for example that if someone says to his wife that if she tell a lie again, she is divorced and then later if she lies again, divorce will automatically occur. My question is that does kufr also happens when done on conditions? i mean if an individual performs a physical act resembling or same as prostration with the intention that if he ever lie, then he is prostrating to worship someone specific other than Allah. If this person later tells a lie, does the prior act of prostration-like bending (which was done with the intention that he is prostrating to worship someone specific other than Allah only if he ever lie in his life) become a form of kufr? I am seeking guidance on the Islamic perspective regarding such conditions and their consequences. Actually I have done this and worried that if I lie, my previous prostration like position would be consider kufr Jazak-Allah khair

Comment: "Actually I have done this ..." ... actually, you have answered your own question. Actually, your question should be how you can get forgiveness. If you had no special idol in mind, I guess (and wait for answers based on Islam) this is not kufr but only, but intentionally, missing the prayer.

Comment: I think it is haram to add conditions to religious obligations, other than the natural ones like "if I'm still alive".